# Explanation of part of a visual cryptography algorithm

Tags: encryption, secret-sharing, terminology, visual-cryptography

I have been working on a project involving visual cryptography and I am stuck with the following problem.

My question is related to this paper, [AN IMPROVED VISUAL CRYPTOGRAPHY SCHEME FOR SECRET HIDING](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.2508&rep=rep1&type=pdf), by R.Youmaran, A. Adler, A. Miri.

Can someone explain how one obtains the values for the matrix $O_{11}^{1'}$?  Which can be seen in *Figure 1* in the paper linked above.  If possible, a step by step procedure would be appreciated.